# SQL - Select number of record based on SUM conditions

Tags: sql, postgresql

if you have a order table, is that possible to select all the records which have sum of amount smaller than $1000, assuming that the table already ordered by amount desc
Example:

```
id product_id amount
1  1          500
2  3          400
3  2          300
4  1          200
```

Get all the orders which have sum of amount smaller than $1000
then it should return 1 & 2, because the sum of amount of 1 and 2 is 900 < 1000

Get all the orders which have sum of amount smaller than $1300
then it should return 1,2,3 because the sum of amount of 1,2,3 is 1200 < 1300

Comment: I guess, it is possible, but there is not a simple query for it, as far as I know.

Comment: yeah my knowledge is limited so that my first idea is have a cursor to run through all the record and try to sum it first, but it is a really bad idea and slow performance, just wonder if there any better solution

Comment: `id` 1 and 3 also has a sum of 800 < 1000. Many other combinations too. What about those?

Comment: Search for running totals - you would create a running total in a subquery, then select from that.

Comment: at least with combinations with 2 products...it would be a cross join where the ids don't match...dont know how to do this for n many combinations

Comment: @Vashi interested, but for easier, I would only take it from the top to the bottom, so that would only 1 and 2 in the end

Comment: And you need combinations of how many `id`s? 2, 3 or variable sizes?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 The result is only from the order table, so I would have list of records I want, then I can join or play around with it later on

Comment: @Vashi think about it like a stack, if I would say the stack limit is 1000, the 1 go in first, then 2 and stack is full, the 3 can't go in anymore

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, sum(t.amount) over (order by t.amount desc) as cume_amount
      from t
     ) t
where cume_amount < 1000;
```

Comment: holy holy, you are my hero, this saved my day

Answer (score 1):

```
with a as ( 
    select  sum(amount) over (order by amount desc ) as amount_1 from test_order
)
select * from a where amount_1 < 1000;
```